# How to calculate duration of time from 2 datetimes in IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: datetime, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Can't subtract a datetime from another datetime in IBM Watson Assistant to find the duration between the 2 datetimes.

I have defined 2 context variable in a dialog in Watson Assistant to hold dates:

```
variable = $base_date  value = "2019-07-01 03:00:00"
variable = $current_date  value = "<? now() ?>"
```

Those values are strings and I can provide them in a response. However, I can't figure out how to convert them to datetime so that I can then subtract `$current_date` from `$base_date` to respond with a duration such as `duration = aa Days, bb Hours, cc Minutes, dd Seconds`. I can't figure out how to convert them to milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970 so that I can then do the math between the two dates.

Context variables:

```
$base_date     "2019-07-01 03:00:00"
$current_date  "<? now() ?>"
```

Response:

```
Base date = <? $base_date ?>
Current date = <? $current_date ?>
```

...above works fine to show user the dates in question as follows:

```
Base date = 2019-07-01 03:00:00
Current date = 2019-05-21 12:24:26
```

However, this does not work...

```
Duration = <? $base_date - $current_date ?>
```

Here is the error I receive, obviously telling me can't subtract 2 strings. I just can't figure out how to convert to a date time or number I can manipulate....

Dialog node error

> Error when updating output with output of dialog node id [Welcome].
>   Node output is [{"text":{"values":["Base date = \nCurrent date =  ... Duration = "],"selection_policy":"sequential"}}] SpEL evaluation
>   error: Expression [ $base_date - $current_date ] converted to [
>   context['base_date'] - context['current_date'] ] at position 0:
>   EL1030E: The operator 'SUBTRACT' is not supported between objects of
>   type 'String' and 'String'

Answer (score 1):

data_henrik's suggestion to delegate this logic to a Cloud Functions action or in a logic layer outside of Watson Assistant is a sound suggestion.  You have to work really hard to do this in Watson Assistant, but it can be done.

Through Integer and substring you can get the individual date parts.

```
  "context": {
    "base_year": "<? T(Integer).parseInt($base_date.substring(0,4)) ?>",
  }
```

You can use the Date constructor from Java to ultimately get the milliseconds value.  I provide `base_year` as a simple example.  For `base_time` I have added indentation for readability.

```
  "context": {
    "base_year": "<? T(Integer).parseInt($base_date.substring(0,4)) ?>",
    "base_time": "<? new Date(
        T(Integer).parseInt($base_date.substring(0,4)),
        T(Integer).parseInt($base_date.substring(5,7)),
        T(Integer).parseInt($base_date.substring(8,10)),
        T(Integer).parseInt($base_date.substring(11,13)),
        0,0).getTime() ?>",
    "current_time": "<? new Date(2019,05,24,22,14,12).getTime() ?>"
  }
```

Then you can respond with the following text:

```
Duration in days = <? ($base_time - $current_time)/(1000*60*60*24) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [IBM Watson Assistent documentation on working with date and time values](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-calculations), including computations. The expression language has several methods to add or subtract values. There are also examples on how to reformat date/time values to serve as input for further computations.

The section on [working with time spans](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-time-spans) might be what you are searching for. You can use operations for **java.util.Date**. [That class has operations to turn the data string into a long with milliseconds since 1970](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

For complex conversions or computations you may want to delegate this to a Cloud Functions action. See this section on [making programmatic calls](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-actions).

Comment: Thanks, @data_henrik. I had looked at that but I guess I what I am missing is how to convert say "2019-07-01 12:34:56" to a time to which I can convert to milliseconds so I can then do the math on it. It seems that the material on time spans and the other allow me to increment/decrement some amount of time units from an anchor date but not calculate the duration of the time span itself.

Comment: I added more details.